# Admob http API instead of SDK - possible?

Tags: admob

I don't like how Admob shows ads. My game has its own style and I want to display ads in its style, using my fonts and appearance, but Admob shows ads differently. The problem is that Admob gives me an SDK, but I would like to request ads via API, where I could get a JSON object with title, description and path to image of ad, so that I could display the ad the way I like it and the way my players will like it. Is Admob API described anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Admob does not provide a http api for many many reasons.